# Python Ignore an Exception and Keep going from where it encountered the Exception

Tags: python, xml

I'm having a bit of an issue. I'm parsing a large xml file using Python. The Problem is that the xml file is unpredictable and sometimes certain elements may not be present in the xml, and because of this Python throws an Exception when it looks for it. I want Python to simply ignore this Exception and move on looking for the next element.

Here is my code at the moment, which doesn't work. If it can't find the element it's looking for it'll just throw an exception and move on out of the try-except block.

```
# now we can parse the xml we fetched.
        try:
            user = {}
            feedLinks = response.getElementsByTagName('gd:feedLink')
            statistics = response.getElementsByTagName('yt:statistics')[0]
            user['id'] = response.getElementsByTagName('id')[0].firstChild.data
            user['channel_title'] = response.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.data
            user['profile_url'] = response.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].getAttribute('href')
            user['author_name'] = response.getElementsByTagName('author')[0].firstChild.firstChild.data
            user['author_uri'] = response.getElementsByTagName('uri')[0].firstChild.data
            user['age'] = response.getElementsByTagName('yt:age')[0].firstChild.data
            user['favourites_url'] = feedLinks[0].getAttribute('href')
            user['contacts_url'] = feedLinks[1].getAttribute('href')
            user['playlists'] = feedLinks[3].getAttribute('href')
            user['subscriptions'] = feedLinks[4].getAttribute('href')
            user['uploads'] = feedLinks[5].getAttribute('href')
            user['new_subscription_videos'] = feedLinks[6].getAttribute('href')
            user['statistics'] = {'last_access':statistics.getAttribute('lastWebAccess'), 
                            'subscriber_count':statistics.getAttribute('subscriberCount'), 
                            'video_watch_count':statistics.getAttribute('videoWatchCount'),
                            'view_count':statistics.getAttribute('viewCount'), 
                            'total_upload_views':statistics.getAttribute('totalUploadViews')}
            user['gender'] = response.getElementsByTagName('yt:gender')[0].firstChild.data
            user['location'] = response.getElementsByTagName('yt:location')[0].firstChild.data
            user['profile_pic_url'] = response.getElementsByTagName('media:thumbnail')[0].getAttribute('url')
            user['username'] = response.getElementsByTagName('yt:username')[0].firstChild.data
        except Exception, error:
            # store the error for logging later
            self.errors.append(str(error) + " from main.py:Crawler")
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest bounding each task with a check for validity before attempting to carry out the task, i.e. check whether Elements contains the 'id' tag before setting user['id'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree
def parse():
                xmlFileName = '/home/shariq/abc2.xml'
                postsList = []
                tree = etree.parse(xmlFileName)
                for post in tree.xpath("//add/doc"):
                    thispost = {}
                    postxpath = tree.getpath(post)
                    for child in post:
                        fieldName = child.get("name").strip()
                        thispost[fieldName] = child.text
                    postsList.append(thispost)
                return postsList
```

Above is the function Which convert XML into python dictionary.

the XML I taken is in the form :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<add>
<doc>
    <field name="country">Serbia</field>
    <field name="date">20110518</field>
    <field name="source">Dan</field>
    <field name="lang">Serbian</field>
    <field name="category">news</field>
    <field name="time">1305744480</field>
    <field name="title">&#268;iste rigole prema Spu&#382;u</field>
    <field name="id">4641119297</field>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <field name="country">France</field>
    <field name="date">20110518</field>
    <field name="harvest_time">1305744480</field>
    <field name="source">Sport24.com</field>
    <field name="source_rank">3</field>
    <field name="lang">French</field>
    <field name="siteurl">http://www.sport24.com</field>
    <field name="category">news</field>
    <field name="time">1305744480</field>
    <field name="title">La plus belle pour Sharapova</field>
    <field name="id">4641119295</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

Once You get the dictionary you problem reduced 1000 times.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is iterate through a dictionary, (i *really* like dictionaries) and do everything you were doing before, but differently. Like so (untested):

```
for key in dicto:
  try: user[key] = response.getElementsByTagName(dicto[key])
  except: print "mumble mumble"; continue
```

It shouldn't take much modification to append `getAttribute` stuff to your data.

Comment: ahh I like this idea a lot, I'll try it now

Answer (score 2):

You can not jump back into a try block after an exception is thrown. It just isn't possible

There are, however, two ways to allow the parsing to continue forward. The first is to break every operation into it's own try block. Not a pretty answer.

The better way to do it is to not let the exception be thrown in the first place. Use if statements to check to see if the data exists and is valid rather than just assuming it is. This way you have full control over what happens each time the file is not formatted correctly.